# Subsample size in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

How is it possible to control the size of the subsample used for the training of each tree in the forest?
According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) of scikit-learn:

> A random forest is a meta estimator that fits a number of decision
> tree classifiers on various sub-samples of the dataset and use
> averaging to improve the predictive accuracy and control over-fitting.
> The sub-sample size is always the same as the original input sample
> size but the samples are drawn with replacement if bootstrap=True
> (default).

So `bootstrap` allows randomness but can't find how to control the number of subsample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scikit-learn doesn't provide this, but you can easily get this option by using (slower) version using combination of tree and bagging meta-classifier:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(), max_samples=0.5)
```

As a side-note, Breiman's random forest indeed doesn't consider subsample as a parameter, completely relying on bootstrap, so approximately (1 - 1 / e) of samples are used to build each tree.

Comment: Don't think that this is the case, as the [API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) reads: "The sub-sample size is always the same as the original input sample size but the samples are drawn with replacement if bootstrap=True (default)".

Answer (score 1):

You can actually modify `_generate_sample_indices` function in [forest.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L76) to change the size of subsample each time. The `fastai` library has actually implemented a function [`set_rf_samples`](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/72286b8b22284a53b07d777783ff5d392a3d45b0/old/fastai/structured.py#L382) for that purpose; it looks like that:

```
def set_rf_samples(n):
    """ Changes Scikit learn's random forests to give each tree a random sample of
    n random rows.
    """
    forest._generate_sample_indices = (lambda rs, n_samples:
        forest.check_random_state(rs).randint(0, n_samples, n))
```

you could add this function to your code

Comment: Answer taken from fast.ai library. Source (https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/72286b8b22284a53b07d777783ff5d392a3d45b0/old/fastai/structured.py)

Answer (score 1):

In version 0.22, scikit-learn added the parameter `max_samples` that can be tuned; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html):

> The sub-sample size is controlled with the `max_samples` parameter if `bootstrap=True` (default), otherwise the whole dataset is used to build each tree.