# How do I specify and search for optimal row and column sampling ratios in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

While learning random forest I came across following points:

- Original dataset D  contains d columns and n rows
- Each bootstrapped dataset Di  contains d′  columns and m rows
- Reduce column sampling ratio d'/d to reduce variance
- Reduce row sampling ratio m/n to reduce variance

I was wondering how can I do this in scikit learn.

**Q1.** If I consider both these ratios as as hyperparameters, then how can I do randomized search for them? Say using something like [`RandomizedSearchedCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) or any other API?

**Q2.** Also I checked [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). It has an attribute `max_sample`. In its description, the doc says `the number of samples to draw from X to train each base estimator`.  But then I am confused with why it use word `max`? Cant we specify fixed sample size anywhere? Is this parameter indeed a row sampling ratio?

**Q3.** Does "random" column sampling makes sense? Or PCA makes more sense, instead? Also if I have to do "random" column  sampling (say if PCA is not possible), how do I do that? Is there any API for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Decision Trees is that they have an **high variance** on the training set on which it is learned

e.g. if the training set is changed, sampled from the same distribution, the tree can be really different from the previous one e.g. **the Decision Tree overfit easily**

To solve this problem Random Forest comes in help, the which, in addition to bootstrapping (bootstrap bagging specifically), introduce also random sampling of  the features

The basic principle of Random Forest is to use a bootstrap bagging in combination of features sampling for each tree to reduce variance. Because ensemble models works better if the sub-models are uncorrelated or at best weakly correlated (there is a Mathematical proof on the subject)

If we had used the same set of features they would be somehow correlated. So to reduce variance and correlation between the models we use boostrap bagging and random feature sampling

Regarding the practical question:

**Q1:** These ratios are basically

- the number of instances to extract from the dataset with replacement (bootstrap)  **= m**
- the random subset of features to extract for each tree **= d'**

And of course you can set these as hyperparameters and use them in a grid search algorithm. With the follow:

- `n_estimators` how many trees in the ensemble to construct
- `max_samples` the number of samples to draw from X to train each base estimator  (regarding the m/n ratio)
- `max_features` regarding d'/d ratio

  ```
   GridSearchCV(cv=5,
                estimator=RandomForestClassifier(...),
                param_grid={'n_estimators': [...], 
                            'max_samples': [...],
                            'max_features': [...]})
  ```

You can also use RandomizedSearchCV, but you then need to specify distribution for your parameters instead of fixed values on which you try the combinations.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_randomized_search.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-randomized-search-py

**Q2**: yes it is the sampling of the instances (or the rows). I don't know why it contains the word max inside.

Side note: till the `0.22` version this hyperparameter [was not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847745/subsample-size-in-scikit-learn-randomforestclassifier) . So when doing bootstrap bagging, it would sample with replacement creating a dataset of the same size of the original input X.

**Q3:** The randomness is used to ensure that there is no correlation between the trees (as explained before). PCA is a totally different thing. PCA is used to reduce the dimensionality of your training set. And in PCA the features are constructed as linear combination of the other features.

This randomness is already inside the RandomForestClassifier implementation. Probably it simply sample with probability 1/d (uniform distribution) from the set of the features